# How to limit record before group by for pagination?

Tags: mysql

I have this query that will LEFT JOIN and GROUP BY to get SUM of column.

```
SELECT 
    c.id, 
    SUM(
        r.score
    ) AS score_sum, 
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN r.is_active = '0' THEN r.negative ELSE 0 END
    ) AS negative_sum
FROM comments AS c
LEFT JOIN rates AS r ON (r.comment_id = c.id)
WHERE r.comment_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.id
```

DB Fiddle link:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=fadba795d8426f91471fa4db83845b6f

The query works, but if the comments records is large (10K for example), I need to implement pagination, how do I modify this query to limit the comments records first before GROUP BY?

In short:

1. Get the first 5 comments by limit to 5
2. Left join the table rates
3. Get the SUM by group by

Example, show the first 4 comments SUM

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use subquery to "select c.id from comments limit N" in the FROM clause.

```
select c.id,
       sum(r.score) as score_sum,
       SUM(
        CASE WHEN r.is_active = '0' THEN r.negative ELSE 0 END
       ) AS negative_sum
from ( select c.id from comments c limit 2) c
LEFT JOIN rates AS r ON (r.comment_id = c.id)
GROUP BY c.id;
```

You may apply order by in the subquery to determine order in which you want to select the comments (Top N).

[DB Fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ba3b1c96b077980dbf9eace3e419b7f3)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT 
    c.id, 
    SUM(
        r.score
    ) AS score_sum, 
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN r.is_active = '0' THEN r.negative ELSE 0 END
    ) AS negative_sum
FROM comments AS c
LEFT JOIN rates AS r ON (r.comment_id = c.id)
WHERE r.comment_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.id 
ORDER BY c.id ASC 
LIMIT 5
```

The rationale behind the above query is that `id` is the Primary key (hence indexed) in your `comments` table. Also, your `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` is on the same column, that is, `id`; so MySQL will first utilize the index on `id` and get first 5 rows (due to `LIMIT`), and then proceed forward to `JOIN` with other tables and do aggregation etc.

**Give it a Try!!** More details here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html

We can *confirm* the same using `EXPLAIN ..` on this query.

Comment: Hi if the table is not joined using primary key but other column, will this still work? Thanks

Comment: @cyberfly When we are joining from first table to second table; the keys on first table does not matter, but the indexing defined on second table matters. If you want to dig deep, read about [Nested Loop Join](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/nested-loop-joins.html) algorithm used by MySQL